# Type mismatch on implicit type class conversion

Tags: scala, implicit

I have the following piece of code

```
  trait HTMLWritable {
    def toHTML: String
  }

  case class User(name: String, age: Int, email: String) extends HTMLWritable {
    override def toHTML: String = s"<div> $name ($age) <a href=$email/> </div>"
  }

  trait HTMLSerializer[T] {
    def serialize(value: T): String
  }

  implicit object UserSerializer extends HTMLSerializer[User] {
    override def serialize(user: User): String = s"<div> ${user.name} (${user.age}) <a href=${user.email}/> </div>"

  }

  implicit class HTMLEnrichment[T](value: T) {
    def toHTML(serializer: HTMLSerializer[T]): String = serializer.serialize(value)
  }

  val john = User("John", 32, "john@domain.com")

  println(john.toHTML(UserSerializer))
```

which produces the following error

```
Error:(30, 23) type mismatch;
 found   : advanced.StackOverflowQuestion.UserSerializer.type
 required: Int
  println(john.toHTML(UserSerializer))
```

the error will disappear if I rename `HTMLWritable`'s `toHTML` method to `toHtml` or in general to something else and keeping the print statement intanct like so

```
 trait HTMLWritable {
    def tohtml: String
  }

  case class User(name: String, age: Int, email: String) extends HTMLWritable {
    override def tohtml: String = s"<div> $name ($age) <a href=$email/> </div>"
  }
```

and the question: Why is the compiler confused here?

I would expect that the class method would be preferred and only defer to the implicit if the method was not found but this type mismatch is a completely different beast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler thinks that `.toHTML` in `john.toHTML(UserSerializer)` is method `HTMLWritable#toHTML` instead of extension method `HTMLEnrichment#toHTML`.

Then according to `HTMLWritable#toHTML` signature, `john.toHTML` is a `String` and `john.toHTML(UserSerializer)` is `john.toHTML.apply(UserSerializer)` i.e. `String#apply` expecting `Int`.

Comment: It would be good to mention that the Scala compiler will never search for an extension method if a method with the same name already exists in that class.

Comment: aye aye aye... of course man. Now I see... It is the apply method of the String that produces the type mismatch. Thanks a ton.